# Iterate through an array defined in other source file

Tags: c, callback

For someone of you maybe a simple question:

How to iterate through an array defined in other c source file.
Here is an example:

## Source file **producer.c**

```
typedef struct 
{
   int   a;
   int   b;
}values;

values myvalues[] =
{
   { 2, 5 }, 
   { 10,15},
   { 20,25},
   { 30,35},
   { 40,45},
};
```

## Source file **consumer.c**

```
static void iterateLoop (void)
{
   int i;
   int x = 5;

   for (i = 0; i< (sizeof(myvalues)/sizeof(values)); i++)
   {
      // Do something with myvalues[i].a;
      if (x != myvalues[i].b)
      {
         // something;

      else
      {
         // something;
      }
   }
}
```

This can be done by using callbacks? I need here a 3rd source file which acts as an interface or consumer can access directly the producer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do for example this:

## You need a header file **values.h**

```
typedef struct
{
  int   a;
  int   b;
} values;
```

## Source file **producer.c**

```
#include "values.h"

values myvalues[] =
{
  { 2, 5 },
  { 10,15 },
  { 20,25 },
  { 30,35 },
  { 40,45 },
};

int nbofvalues = sizeof(myvalues) / sizeof(myvalues[0]);
```

## Source file **consumer.c**

```
#include "values.h"

extern values myvalues[];
extern int nbofvalues;

static void iterateLoop(void)
{
  int i;
  int x = 5;

  for (i = 0; i < nbofvalues; i++)
  {
    // Do something with myvalues[i].a;
    if (x != myvalues[i].b)
    {
      // something;
    }
    else
    {
      // something;
    }
  }
}
```